# Multiply word by preceding number in text file

Tags: unix, text, terminal

I've got a large .txt file on this format:

```
  4 yes
  3 this
  2 is
  1 dog
```

I want to multiply each word with the preceding number and get something like this:

```
  yes
  yes
  yes
  yes
  this
  this
  this
  is
  is
  dog
```

I am currently working on Unix (LMDE). What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=$1;i++) print $2 }' file.txt
```